# Wordpress menu's class missing

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Im starting with wordpress and I have a problem with a menu Im doing. In functions.php, I have this:

```
register_nav_menus(array(
   'principal' => 'principal_bar'
));
```

Very simple. Now, in my header.php, I have this:

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
   'container' => false,
   'items_wrap' => '<ul>%3$s</ul>',
   'theme_location' => 'principal',
   'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right'
));
```

As you can see, Im (trying) to use bootstrap classes in my menu. The thing is that when I edit my menu in the wordpress visual interface, the menu_class of my menu is removed (in Inspector, the ul ends with no class), and obviously the visual aspect of my menu is totally broken. My answer, Did I miss something? All tutos give the same way to do menus, but mine is not taking the classes at all. Am I doing something wrong here? Or is a problem bootstrap-wordpress? I am really confused right now... Thank you very much for your help...

Answer (score 0):

You missing some properties in you `items_wrap`, should be:

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
  'container' => false,
  'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
  'theme_location' => 'principal',
  'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right'
));
```